# For each element in array return whole array without this element

Tags: python, arrays

I want my code to return, for every element in array, this array but without this one element. 
Example: for array `numbers=[1,2,3]` I want output `"[2,3]","[1,3]","[1,2]"`

I've used this code:

```
examp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for number in examp:
  print(str(number) + " MAIN")
  subExp = examp
  subExp.remove(number)
  print(subExp)
```

but this one outputs (word "MAIN" is used as information which element is right now "subtracted" from array):

```
1 MAIN
[2, 3, 4, 5]
3 MAIN
[2, 4, 5]
5 MAIN
[2, 4]
```

For this code above I would expect this:

```
1 MAIN
[2, 3, 4, 5]
2 MAIN
[1, 3, 4, 5]
3 MAIN
[1, 2, 4, 5]
4 MAIN
[1, 2, 3, 5]
5 MAIN
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It's probably some stupid mistake from my side, but as a beginner in this topic, I coudn't find answer anywhere, so if there's any better way to do it, please help

Comment: For the top example you can do list(itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3],2))

Comment: `subExp = examp` modifying a list in a loop without copying it first, it's a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
subExp = examp
```

Here `subExp` isn't a copy of `examp`, but rather just another pointer just like `examp` to the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. So in each iteration of your `for` loop you remove one entry of the list.

You can replace that line with:

```
subExp = examp.copy()
```

which will make a shallow copy of `examp`. Although this works for flat lists, you'd get in trouble for nested lists. In general you want to use `copy` package's

```
subExp = copy.deepcopy(examp)
```

**EDIT**: If you don't need to do the print line, then `itertools.combinations()` is the way to go. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations for more info

Answer (score 1):

For these you can use itertools:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3,4,5],4))                                                                                                                                       
# [(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a range, then output arrays filtered by index

```
examp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for x in range(0, len(examp)):
    print(f'iteration {x + 1} ->')
    print([el for i, el in enumerate(examp) if i != x])
```

or using itertools

```
print(list(itertools.combinations(examp, len(examp) - 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list, slicing out the current element:

```
examp = [7, False, "OOpS", 3.14159]

for i in range(len(examp)):
    print(examp[:i] + examp[i+1:])
```

Output:

```
[False, 'OOpS', 3.14159]
[7, 'OOpS', 3.14159]
[7, False, 3.14159]
[7, False, 'OOpS']
```